# How do I use an if statement using datetime format with colons without encountering errors

Tags: python, datetime

I wish to use an if statement in Python to sort times into a category as follows:

```
blood_glucose_readings = readings["Historic Glucose mmol/L"]

dates_and_times = readings["Device Timestamp"]

for x in dates_and_times:
   x = datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')

reading_times_hours = dates_and_times.str.slice(10, 16)

reading_dates = dates_and_times.str.slice(0, 10)


if reading_times_hours >= 4:00 and reading_times_hours <= 11:00:
    morning_reading == True
else:
    morning_reading == False
```

All code works flawlessly except the if statement which returns the ending colon as a syntax error. Why is this?

Comment: I don't do Python, but I imagine a literal of `4:00` is not going to work. What format is `reading_times_hours`? If this is a string, then you want to compare against `'4:00'` instead (i.e. with quotes).

Comment: x = datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
you are not using this anywhere.

Comment: no, it is the datetime format but, i will try the suggestion thankyou

Comment: i thought this formatted the date to the datetime format

Answer (score 1):

Convert reading_times_hours to str. Cannot compare malformed int to str(i assume dates_and_times returns a str)

```
if reading_times_hours == "4:00" and reading_times_hours == "11:00":
   morning_reading == True
else:
   morning_reading == False
```